# how to write ng-if logic into controller

Tags: angularjs

Would like to move my ng-if logic into controller.
here if my condition in HTML

```
<div data-ng-if="transfer.fromAccount.number !== '12538855' && transfer.status === 'Completed'" >
</div>
```

Comment: Well, do it. What is your question? Have you tried anything? Which problem did you face?

Comment: Actually, i need to do this comparison in controller instead of in ng-if directive. I guess i can pass true false value using function?

Comment: You can *return* true or false from a function, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke a method on your controller inside you `ng-if` directive.

```
<div data-ng-if="$ctrl.checkX()" >
</div>


/// Your controller
function checkX() {
   return transfer.fromAccount.number !== '12538855' && transfer.status === 'Completed';
}
```

this code is a demonstration, it probably won't work cause you will need to use your method.

Comment: Thanks its working.. Can you please help me to write UT for this? `trans = (external) => {
       if (external.fromAccount.routingNumber != 12538855 && external.status == 'Completed'){
            return true
    
    }`